# javascript: scroll a div to the bottom

Tags: javascript, html, scroll

I have code like

```
function scrollme(){
dh=document.body.scrollHeight
ch=document.body.clientHeight
if(dh>ch){
moveme=dh-ch
window.scrollTo(0,moveme)
}
}
```

But I want it to only scroll a div named "feed" not the whole page. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
document.getElementById('feed').scrollTop = y;
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.scrollTop